# Escaping array in vkbeautify.js

Tags: javascript

I'm using vkbeautify.js plugin. I'm struck at a simple problem.
Currently upon parsing some json, the output is

```
vkbeautify.json({"score":[{"range":[25, 2]}]})
```

**Output**

```
"{  
    "score": [  
        {  
            "range": [  
                25,  
                2  
            ]  
        }  
    ]  
}"
```

But, I'm expecting...

```
"{  
    "score": [  
        {  
            "range": [25,2]  
        }  
    ]  
}"
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, current vkbeautify.json implementation is a wrapper for native JSON object, which does the job. So, there is no way to manipulate with output. But there are other branches, for example "soap"
https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify/blob/soap/vkbeautify.js
where json part is implemented with regex. You can play with those branches to implement desired layout.

Answer (score 3):

vkBeautify doesn't have an option to handle the output you desire. For JSON the only option is the indentation value.

You may see more about vkBeautify here: https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify

---

You may want to suggest this as a feature through a pull request on github. It does sound like a useful feature.

---

**Update 1**

Actually, what you request isn't easily implemented in the library. The reason is that [the code](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify/blob/master/vkbeautify.js#L153-L163) is using the Browser's implementation of [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

You might try parsing the response from vkbeautify.json(), but this won't be very easy as arrays can contain other objects, arrays, integers, doubles, etc. You *might* be able to determine a RegEx, but it would be very extreme and inefficient. You would need another approach through some sort of recursion.